# Background url not working when trying to change image on hover

Tags: html, css

I have problem with my project. I´m trying to change picture when i hover on it. So I tried to find something on this forum, but solution that worked for everyone is not my soltion.

```
.img1{
    width: 130px;
    height: 195px;
    background: url("/img/rorschach1.jpg");
    display: inline-block;
}
.img1:hover {
    background: url("/img/rorschach2.jpg");
}
```

HTML part

```
<div class="img1"></div>
```

I tried using this without " - not worked
My directory is:

```
    IP_projekt
    │   Projekt_s1.html
    │
    ├───css
    │       style_s1.css
    │
    ├───icon
    │       icon.png
    │
    └───img
            aqua1.jpg
            aqua2.jpg
            geometry1.jpg
            geometry2.jpg
            natural1.jpg
            natural2.jpg
            paint1.jpg
            paint2.jpg
            rorschach1.jpg
            rorschach2.jpg
```

When I try to change background: `url("/img/rorschach1.jpg")`; to `background: url("/IP_Projekt/img/rorschach1.jpg");` it open image when i ctrl+click in Visual Code but don´t open on html.

Comment: Does it show image rorschach1?

Comment: What error are you getting in console?

Comment: No.. Akhil Nayak

Comment: Laif I´m using stream server to instantly see what I did so I don´t have console

Comment: Try opening it in a browser and seeing what error it throws. A stream server can be useful but you can't fully rely on it.

Comment: @BasterCz have your tried to return a level in directory hierarchy? `../img/rorschach1.jpg`, because the css file is inside one directory, and images are in another, there's no `img` folder inside `css` folder

Comment: Try taking off the first slash

Comment: rorschach1.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @CalvinNunes I tried. No error but image wasn´t there

Comment: @BasterCz change `background` to `background-image`

Comment: @Laif this isn´t that

Comment: @BasterCz What?

Comment: How about adding a single dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is with file hierarchy. Also change `background` to `background-image`.

change `background: url("/img/rorschach1.jpg");` to `background-image: url("../img/rorschach1.jpg");`

Comment: GET file:///D:/%C5%A0kola/IP/IP_projekt/css/img/rorschach1.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @BasterCz Edited again

Comment: @BasterCz You're getting the image now but you are getting some other issue. Are you positive the image is valid? Navigate to //D:/%C5%A0kola/IP/IP_projekt/img/rorschach1.jpg and see if it appears in console

Comment: yes, ins Visual Code I ctrl+LClick on that directory and that oped image, bud on side image isn´t there and there´s no error in console

Comment: What do you see when you navigate to the file loc in browser?

Comment: Maby I know where is problem. That image was converted from png to jpg by online convertor so there´s  problem. I tried that with another picture that was originaly jpg and it worked. sorry for problems. So your comment is answer to errors in console.